# Trouble reading from a file and putting values into an array of structs

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dynamic, struct

Problem: I am having trouble taking input from a .csv file and sticking it into an array of structs. My problem is that the compiler will not let me assign G.word from my char variable word. I am clueless as to why not since both my structure and the initial place holder variable consist of the same type. Thank you. It has to be in C but the assignment lets us use the C++ functions to deal with the file. Other than that I am stuck with C.

```
/*Sample of the data being read. 
airport 2007    175702  32788
airport 2008    173294  31271
request 2005    646179  81592
request 2006    677820  86967
request 2007    697645  92342
request 2008    795265  125775
*/

struct NGram{
char *nword;
int year;
int wordCount;
int uText;
};

char fileName[]="very_short.csv";

int main() {
char word[81];
int year;
int wordCount;
int uniqueTextCount;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

int size = 100000; //initialize array at 100000
struct NGram G[size];

FILE *inFile;    // declare file pointer
inFile = fopen( fileName,"r");

while( fscanf( inFile, "%s %d %d %d", word, &year, &wordCount, &uniqueTextCount) != EOF) {
    //printf("%s %d %d %d\n", word, year, wordCount, uniqueTextCount);

        if (year > 1800 && year < 2000) { //store values in struct only if between these dates
        G[j].nword = word;
        G[j].year = year;
        G[j].wordCount = wordCount;
        G[j].uText = uniqueTextCount;
            j++;
        }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So are you really writing C or C++? C code for this might compile as C++, but will be awful C++ code. Decent C++ code for this won't compile as C at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry about that seems it didn't copy. *fixed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It has to be in C but the assignment lets us use the C++ functions to deal with the file. Other than that I am stuck with C.

Comment: Also, on a machine with 32bit `int` and default padding/alignment, that `G[]` array is going to be approximately 2400000 bytes, ~ 2.29 MB. May want to make sure you have that much available on your platform. And this: `G[j].nword = word` I can all but guarantee you isn't doing what you think it is. When finished every `G[]` entry you manufacture will point to the *same* buffer (`word[81]` in `main()`). And whats with the `i` loop?

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah I can't seem to figure that one out. I would think that it's just using word as a temp for the struct. Why would it point to word[81] if they are each being set to their respective struct counterpart?

Comment: @Rbutler93 think again. Every `G[j].nword = word` stores the based address of that array (`word`) in the indexed structure's `nword` member. I.e. when all is done you'll have every structure `nword` member pointing to the *same* buffer, which will be holding the last successfully loaded entry *only*. Not that it matters, this code is destined for undefined behavior the moment you read more than one line with an in-range year (`j` officially exceeds the size of `G` from then on. The loops in this are a mess.

Comment: One thing which jumps out at me, the `year` conditional, doesn't look like it'll do what you want.  One thing it's not using the logical OR(||), it's using the bitwise OR(|).  Also the conditions don't seem right. Greater than 1800 OR less than 2000 which basically means any year.

Comment: Morphing the posted code for anything besides a typo correct isn't the way to do this. It makes every comment/answer referring to what is no longer there nonsensical. With that i'm out. Best of luck, and I hope you catch a break.

Comment: Now you excluded every year in your sample since none of them are in that range.

Comment: @tinstaafl yes that is what I wanted to do I want it to only place the values in the structure that are within that range. I accidentally copied the old code I was  working on.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong method to copy arrays to pointer.  Need to allocate memory and then copy with `memcpy()`.

```
// char *nword;
// char word[81];
// G[j].nword = word;

size_t wsize = strlen(word) + 1;
G[j].nword = (char *) malloc(wsize);  // drop cast if compiling in C, could add NULL check
memcpy(G[j].nword, word, wsize);
```

A simple C method to read line orientated files is to read 1 *line* and then parse it.   Use `fgets()` rather than `fscanf()`.   Use `"%n"` to note where scanning stopped.

```
// Zero fill G.  Not truly needed but simplifies debugging.
struct NGram G[size] = { 0 }; 

char buf[200];
size_t j = 0;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf,  inFile) != NULL) {
  if (j >= size) break;  // Too many
  char word[81];
  NGram Nbuf;
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "%80s %d %d %d %n", word, &Nbuf.year, &Nbuf.wordCount, &Nbuf.uText, &n);
  // If all fields were not scanned or something left at the end ...
  if (n == 0 || buf[n]) {
    puts("Bad Input");
    break;
  }
  if (Nbuf.year > 1800 && Nbuf.year < 2000) {
    size_t wsize = strlen(word) + 1;
    Nbuf.nword = (char *) malloc(wsize);  // drop cast if compiling in C
    memcpy(Nbuf.nword, word, wsize);
    G[j] = Nbuf;
    j++
  }
}

// Do something with G[0] to G[j-1]

// free each ( 0 to j-1) G[].nword when done.
```